# How to save a rich text box to a python file with c #

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to save a rich text box to a Python file but when I save I get a file like this:
{\ rtf1 \ ansi \ ansicpg1252 \ deff0 \ nouicompat \ deflang1033 {\ fonttbl {\ f0 \ fnil \ fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
{\ * \ generator Riched20 10.0.22526} \ viewkind4 \ uc1
\ pard \ f0 \ fs17 print ("kl") \ par
}
How can I fix this?

Code:

```
var sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "python file | *.py";
if(sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    richTextBox1.SaveFile(sfd.FileName);
    textBox1.Text = sfd.FileName;
}
```

Comment: A rich text box holds _rich text_ (i.e., not just the text, but the formatting as well). The RTF format holds that formatting information in a text stream. That's what you are seeing. Check out @pm100's answer

Answer (score 1):

Example in MS docs. You need to add second arg to savefile

```
public void SaveMyFile()
{
   // Create a SaveFileDialog to request a path and file name to save to.
   SaveFileDialog saveFile1 = new SaveFileDialog();

   // Initialize the SaveFileDialog to specify the RTF extension for the file.
   saveFile1.DefaultExt = "*.rtf";
   saveFile1.Filter = "RTF Files|*.rtf";

   // Determine if the user selected a file name from the saveFileDialog.
   if(saveFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK &&
      saveFile1.FileName.Length > 0) 
   {
      // Save the contents of the RichTextBox into the file.
      richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFile1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
   }
}
```